# FUOC Flash while implementing light/dark theme with Tailwind CSS and Next.js 14

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project using Tailwind CSS and Next.js 14 and facing FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content).

I'm taking the user's system theme preference into account while also providing a manual button to toggle light/dark mode.

I tried various approaches, including an inline script in the `RootLayout` and importing a client component (using `useEffect`) into `RootLayout`, but haven't been able to eliminate the flash.

And I don't want to use `_document.jsx`.